# jquery click .addClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, addclass, removeclass

Hi i have been having trouble all day with this, it almost works but not quite, i need the corresponding p (#p-1 etc) to stay highlighted once the thumb nail is clicked. I have used a Plug in for an image slider which i have customized slightly and the mouseover and mouseleave events are working fine but the click event doesn't appear to add the class to the target paragraph.

Example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RVYnb/7/

The relevant jQuery is written inline on the example.

this is driving me crazy, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the image slider plugin. It also binds to the click event in the code.

Here's the relevant code part in the plugin:

```
jQuery("div#thumbSlider" + j + " a").each(function(z) {            
            jQuery(this).bind("click", function(){
                jQuery(this).find("p.tmbrdr").css({borderColor: settings.thumbsActiveBorderColor, opacity: settings.thumbsActiveBorderOpacity});
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("p.tmbrdr").not(jQuery(this).find("p.tmbrdr")).css({borderColor: settings.thumbsBorderColor, opacity: settings.thumbsBorderOpacity});
                var cnt = -(pictWidth*z);
                (cnt != container.find("ul").css("left").replace(/px/, "")) ? container.find("span.typo").animate({"opacity": 0}, 250) : null ;
                container.find("ul").animate({ left: cnt}, settings.easeTime, settings.easeFunc, function(){container.find("span.typo").animate({"opacity": settings.typoFullOpacity}, 250)});                    
                return false;
            });
        });
```

The problem is the "return false" at the end. It stopps the propagation to other click events.

Change the code to the following:

```
Query(this).bind("click", function(e){
                    jQuery(this).find("p.tmbrdr").css({borderColor: settings.thumbsActiveBorderColor, opacity: settings.thumbsActiveBorderOpacity});
                    jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("p.tmbrdr").not(jQuery(this).find("p.tmbrdr")).css({borderColor: settings.thumbsBorderColor, opacity: settings.thumbsBorderOpacity});
                    var cnt = -(pictWidth*z);
                    (cnt != container.find("ul").css("left").replace(/px/, "")) ? container.find("span.typo").animate({"opacity": 0}, 250) : null ;
                    container.find("ul").animate({ left: cnt}, settings.easeTime, settings.easeFunc, function(){container.find("span.typo").animate({"opacity": settings.typoFullOpacity}, 250)});                    
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
```

and it should work.

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking, this enables the clicked class to be added which is great, however it makes the page refresh or jump to the top, when the thumbnail is clicked. which is a big issue if someones looking through an image gallery! any idea why this happens.? thanks

Comment: Hm, ok. The e.preventDefault() should prevent that. Also on the jsFiddle example i can't reproduce this behaviour.
Maybe it helps if you also add e.preventDefault() your own functions.

Comment: You bloody lovely person you. If i could hug you i would! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, according to the "fiddle", that your "click" event isn't working on your thumbnails. It's never adding the "clicked" class to your

.

I threw an "alert" into this:

```
$("#t1").live("click", function() {
    alert('clicking');
    $("#p-1").addClass("clicked").addClass("highlighted");
});
```

and the alert never popped.

Comment: i noticed the clicked class wasn't being added, but i cant for the life of me, work out why! its infuriating as i have been trying different implementations all day

Comment: yeah... i've been fiddling with the fiddle (no pun intended) for quite a bit, now. It must be that plugin that is canceling the event, but I cannot see where.

Comment: XD. thanks for your help so far, as far as i can see the click event is valid. but it never gets added. down see why click is being picked on, and not mouseleave/over.

Comment: ok... I got it... add your events, the ones you are creating via "live" into the "onload" event where you are starting up the thumbnail plugin. Put it right after it. Oh, and for some reason "live", for the click events wasn't working for me. I changed them to regular "click" events and it's working.

Comment: do you mean in the inline jQuery? can you show me on the fiddle please. thansk